# how can i save a list into sqlite database in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

i receive a list from a rest service and i want to save it to sqlite database in app.
this is my code:

```
    async void ClickOnStartAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstAnswerService = await App.userManager.GetAnswerItemAsync("1");
        Answer ans_item = new Answer();
        try
        {
        foreach (var item in lstAnswerService)
        {
            ans_item.ans_Id = item.ans_Id;
            ans_item.qu_Id = item.qu_Id;
            ans_item.ans_Title = item.ans_Title;
            ans_item.isAnswer = item.isAnswer;
            ans_item.sortId = item.sortId;

            //Code for saving ans_item into sqlite database in app
        }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("", ex.Message.ToString(), "ok");
        }
    }
```

I want save list lstAnswerService into sqlite

my class and table Answerr is like below:

```
public class Answer
{
    [PrimaryKey,AutoIncrement]
    public int ans_Id { get; set; }
    public int qu_Id { get; set; }
    public string ans_Title { get; set; }
    public bool isAnswer { get; set; }
    public int sortId { get; set; }
}
```

How can i do this?

Comment: have you read the docs?  All you should have to do is create a sqlite connection and call Insert for each item in the list.  What specific part don't you understand how to do?

Comment: @Jason I created a sqlite connection but it doesn't work, Can you complete my code for inserting into sqlite?

Comment: please show the code you've written and explain "doesn't work".  Are you getting an error or exception?  Using Sqlite with Forms is well documented and there are many sample apps available from Xamarin.

Comment: @Jason Thanks, I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to create new object of Answer list Like and after that` List<Answer>  objLstAnswer = new List<Answer>` and in foreach loop you need to add ans_item object into list Like `objLstAnswer.Add(ans_item)`

Full Code below`                                               
  List<Answer>  objLstAnswer = new List<Answer>
  lstAnswerService = await App.userManager.GetAnswerItemAsync("1");
        Answer ans_item = new Answer();
        try
        {
        foreach (var item in lstAnswerService)
        {
            ans_item.ans_Id = item.ans_Id;
            ans_item.qu_Id = item.qu_Id;
            ans_item.ans_Title = item.ans_Title;
            ans_item.isAnswer = item.isAnswer;
            ans_item.sortId = item.sortId;
            objLstAnswer.Add(ans_item);
        }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("", ex.Message.ToString(), "ok");
        }`
```